# EasyMock mock new instance of a class with arguments

Tags: junit4, powermock, easymock

So I'm trying to get rid of `PowerMock` as I'm updating to `java 17` by using `EasyMock.`

But I hit a wall trying to convert this :

```
PowerMock.expectNew(File.class, "path").andReturn(fileMock).times(1);
```

Into the `Easymock` alternative.
I wrote smth like this.

`EasyMock.expect(new File("path")).andReturn(fileMock).times(1);`

But it doesn't seem to work, and I keep hitting
`java.lang.IllegalStateException: no last call on a mock available.`

Any ideas would be welcome. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can't mock `new` with EasyMock. It's not supported. But I will argue that you do not need to mock File. You can just create and actual file.

If needed, extract to a method the piece of code creating the `File`, create a partial mock and make that method returning a `File` that suits your purpose.